# Why can we assume electric field to be uniform to calculate flux?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

In this video https://youtu.be/jYMSdBUhrDo at 3:25  in the side view of the ring, why we consider the $E$ value which they have calculated at axis to be same for whole area of blue shaded part? And similarly, in the curved surface part why the elctric field $E_p$ will be same at whole curved surface? Also without Gauss's law, can we arrive at same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lecturer states several time that he is assuming that the radius of the ring, $R_0$, is much, much greater than the radius of the Gaussian cylinder, $t$ so aver the area $\pi t^2$ he assumes that the electric field is approximately constant.

*Also without gauss law can we arrive at same result ?*
[Off-axis electric field of a ring of charge](http://www.mare.ee/indrek/ephi/efield_ring_of_charge.pdf).

Comment: Sir do u have the same for magnetic field at off axis of a rotating ring too? And can u see my other post which considers a gaussian surface just wanted to know if that is correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

Gauss's law is always true (in a static situation) but is only useful when you have high symmetry in the charge distribution so that you can choose Gaussian surfaces that permit easy calculation of the flux.  In theory you can also find the field at a point by summing contributions from small increments of charge using Coulombs law.

Comment: Here Sir used that law to calculate flux , from there he derived offaxis field very close to centre

Comment: Hmm yeah Sir using coulombs law too it can be solved